# IndexError: list index out of range when iterating two webelements lists

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to print the result on the terminal but getting this error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Below is the code, thanks in advance for your help. 
Truly beginner to this field.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Sheik\\Desktop\\web crawling\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(5000)

url = "https://www.yell.com/"

driver.get(url)

search_query_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="search_keyword"]''')
search_query_path.click()
search_query_path.send_keys("Garage Services")
search_city_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="search_location"]''')
search_city_path.click()
search_city_path.send_keys("London")
search_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="searchBoxForm"]/fieldset/div[1]/div[3]/button''')
search_btn.click()


names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("businessCapsule--name")
address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("businessCapsule--address")

num_page_items = len(names)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print(f"{names[num_page_items].text} : {address[num_page_items].text}")

driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you append Backtrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the index `i` to iterate over `names` and `address`, not the list size

```
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print(f"{names[i].text} : {address[i].text}")
```

Or just loop on both with `zip`

```
for name, ad in zip(names, address):
    print(f"{name.text} : {ad.text}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the list with the length of it instead of the iterator variable `i`

```
print(f"{names[num_page_items].text} : {address[num_page_items].text}")
```

to

```
print(f"{names[i].text} : {address[i].text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. To extract all the *names* and *addresses* from the webpage https://www.yell.com/  you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  names = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.businessCapsule--name")))]
  address = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.businessCapsule--address")))]
  for i,j in zip(names, address):
      print("{} address is {}".format(i, j))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Diagnostic Services And Repairs Ltd address is 7.7 mi | R/O 310 Green Lanes, London, N13 5TT
  Maypole Motors Ltd address is 11.5 mi | We serve London | Surbiton, KT6
  Allen & Hall Motor Engineers Ltd address is 13.3 mi | We serve London | Romford, RM7
  Ryecraft Motors & Body Shop address is 4.1 mi | 1a Old James St, London, SE15 3TS
  M & K Garage Services address is 7.5 mi | 4 Oak Grove Rd, London, SE20 7RQ
  Daytona Garage address is 4.9 mi | 98 Vale Rd, London, N4 1PZ
  Mobile Hybrid Repair Ltd address is 37.8 mi | We serve London | Reading, RG30
  C & E Motors address is 5.1 mi | Unit 6 Brookmarsh Trading Estate, Norman Rd, London, SE10 9QE
  Stevens Motors address is 8.2 mi | 3a Wellington Rd, London, E11 2AN
  M V Motor Repairs address is 5.6 mi | 7 Bidder St, London, E16 4ST
  Carpenters Garage address is 6.1 mi | 69 Bickersteth Rd, London, SW17 9SH
  Car Care Ealing address is 8.2 mi | 199 Northfield Avenue, London, W13 9QU
  German Car Centre address is 7.3 mi | Unit 3, Hyde Estate Road, LONDON, NW9 6JX
  Defoe Tyres Ltd address is 4.2 mi | 1a Defoe Rd, London, N16 0EP
  Kwik Kar Service Centre address is 3.8 mi | 11 West Hampstead Mews, London, NW6 3BB
  DPF Specialist Clinic address is 5.7 mi | 115 Lea Bridge Rd, London, E10 7AG
  Blueflash Garage address is 3 mi | 21-25 Bedford Rd, Clapham North, London, SW4 7SH
  National Tyres and Autocare address is 7.1 mi | 57 Kingston Road, London, SW19 1JN
  National Tyres and Autocare address is 7.8 mi | 92-96 St Marys Road, Ealing, London, W5 5EX
  Merton Autotechnics address is 7 mi | Unit 5 Station Rd, London, SW19 2LP
  The Old Forge Garage address is 11.9 mi | We serve London | Belvedere, DA17
  Green Man Tyre & Exhaust Ltd address is 8.8 mi | 1308 High Rd, London, N20 9HJ
  Castle Motors Ltd address is 6.9 mi | The Rear Of Number 1 Sansom Rd, London, E11 3EY
  National Tyres and Autocare address is 7.3 mi | We serve London | The Hyde, Hendon, NW9
  Walthamstow Village Garage address is 7.3 mi | 28 Ravenswood Rd, London, E17 9LY
  ```